# Redirect to a VF Page hosted on Force.com site with Cookie Data

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, force.com-sites, cookies

I have a requirement to pass information to a visualforce page hosted on a Force.com Site in a secured manner, and not using query string.

I had used cookies for this purpose. However, on the host page, no cookie is getting passed, and I am getting null values over there.

On the contrary, when I created the same page in my own org, and called the vf page after setting the cookies, I am getting all the cookies values.

Seems like there is a different provision for sending cookies data to external sites. Can anyone pls help?

Force.com Side Controller Class :

```
public class WelcometoSitePageCtrl {
    public String email{get;set;}
    public String SubscriptionNo{get;set;}
    public String returnUrl{get;set;}
    public String name{get;set;}
    public String address1{get;set;}
    public String address2{get;set;}
    public String Country{get;set;}
    
    public WelcometoSitePageCtrl() {
        System.debug('Params'+ApexPages.CurrentPage().getCookies().get('email'));
        email = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getCookies().get('email').getValue(); - This is null
    }
}
```

On having the same code within my salesforce instance, I am successfully getting the data.

Response when I have this page in same Salesforce Instance :

[image]

Response when I have this Visualforce page on Force.com site

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use cookies, they must be prefixed with `apex__`. This is outlined in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_sites_cookie.htm). Note that you can't just send arbitrary cookies across domains, either, so your solution probably won't work.

I suggest you simply encrypt the parameters and pass them in the URL. This is easily done with the [Crypto class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm), and should be considered secure as long as you don't leak the private key.

Comment: the same implementation is working fine, and cookies are getting passed when I place my page in the same instance of Salesforce.